# Can't delete a deployed printer from users computers

Tags: group-policy, network-printer, windows-server-2012-r2

I am facing some weird issues when trying to remove a printer from the users machines on my domain  that was deployed with Group policy.
When I try to remove it I get  **"access deny"** message **even tho I login as admin**. The policy is targeting computers only.
How can I accomplish this without going back to the policy and filtering users? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you logged in as admin or domain admin?

Comment: As Admin but no luck.

Comment: Try domain admin

Comment: Just tried, I get **access is denied, unable to remove device**. Thanks tho.

Comment: Are there any jobs in the queue? If there are, stop the queue and delete them.